# swi-prolog strange recursion write

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a similar recursion function:

```
fillTable(X0,Y0,Yn,Yh):-
   checkPoint(X0,Y0),
   Ynext = Y0+Yh,
   Ynext=<Yn,
   fillTable(X0,Ynext,Yn,Yh).

checkPoint(X,Y):-
     (-X-1)<Y,
     X<0, Y<0,
     write(X), writeq(' '), write(Y),write(' in 1 area'),
     nl,
     !
  ;
     (-X+1)>Y, X>0, Y>0,
     write(X),write(' '), write(Y),write(' in 2 area'),
     nl,
     !
  ;
     write(X),write(' '),write(Y),write(' not in area'),nl.
```

Where X, Y and other var's are `float`, but when it's written by `write()`, it prints `-1+0.2+0.2+0.2+...` not `-0.8, -0.6` or other.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common beginner's issue in Prolog to confuse "unification" with "assignment".

Your expression:

```
Ynext = Y0+Yh,
```

Does not *assign* the value of `Y0+Yh` to the variable `Ynext`. The predicate `=/2` is the unification predicate, which will take the expressions on both sides and unify them. These expressions are `Ynext`, a variable, and `Y0+Yh`, which is the functor `+/2` applied to two other variables (which in your case, are instantiated). In other words, it unifies `Ynext` with `+(Y0,Yh)` and does not evaluate it.

Let's suppose then you have `Y0` instantiated as `-1` and `Yh` as `0.2`. Then, the unification expression above will be:

```
Ynext = -1+0.2,
```

Which will result in `Ynext` having the value `-1+0.2` (which is, in prolog, the same as `+(-1,0.2)`.

If you want to evaluate the arithmetic expression and assign it, you'd use `is/2`:

```
Ynext is Y0 + Yh,
```

Note that the inequalities `</2`, `>/2`, etc do evaluate. So the expression:

```
(-X+1)>Y
```

Will do what you expect it to, which is to succeed or fail depending upon whether the value of the arithmetic expression `(-X+1)` is less than the value of `Y` or not.